# Cloud based Inventory Management Software for linking with Shopify

Tags: cloud-service, inventory, shopping

### I am looking for something that can:

- Support international customers as I am based in Tokyo.
- Integrate with Shopify.
- Manage inventory from said platform.
- Connect to other non-integrated sales channels (manually if need be).
- Differentiate between the stock inside each sales channel and subtract accordingly in regards to the base inventory.
- Big plus if they have integrations with Farfetch.
- Have invoicing software that can do:

  - Order confirmation.
  - Installment invoicing, e.g: 30%/70% or 30%/60%/10%)
  - Shipping invoice (for customs).
  - Customizable detailed shipping invoices especially in regards to making product variant quantity readable and compact. e.g: 1 product on 1 row but showing the quantity for sizes; S, M, L etc ...
- B2B wholesale management or portal functionality.
- Wholesale sales order CSV/Excel download export functionality.
- Partial batch delivery invoice processing. (if a wholesale shipment is split into two batches can the system invoice the customer in relation to the batch and update the remaining orders to be fulfilled in the rest of the wholesale order for that customer)

### I have tried:

- Katana - it seems to be based more towards people selling products that have a sort of build time. While this portion of the application can be ignored I am just curious if there are other solid options.
- ZOHO Inventory: While their collective suite might be a good product. For my needs the product's invoicing software was a little lacking in the customization. Furthermore, after talking to a representative it seemed that the need to also install ZOHO Invoice wouldn't be needed because most of the features that are built into the Inventory product are about 90% of what is included in the Invoice product.
- Shopify Plus (Currently talking to their sales team but at the time of this edit all they have said is that they usually charge from $24,000. I still don't know if they can accommodate my conditions.)
- TradeGecko: Currently trying out their software to see if it is the right fit. So far so good and after talking to a representative they said their product team is currently working on an implementation with Farfetch.
- Microsoft Dynamics: Inquired, way to expensive and big of a scope for the size of my business. The small plan started at $400k/y and the plan above that started at around $2mil/y.
- StitchLabs: Looked into them and they seemed like a pretty good fit but per their sign up form it seemed like they were only offering service to US based customers.

  - Zangerine: also not available outside the US.

### Planning on trying:

- Netsuite: Just started the 14 day trial today. They currently run around $2,000 a month.
- JOR